# How to test slugged url with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I have an rails application where i used slugged urls. How can i test those urls with Rspec.

rake routes is generating following results

```
new_user_session GET    /login(.:format)                   sessions#new
    user_session POST   /login(.:format)                   sessions#create
            bays GET    /:slug/bays(.:format)              bays#index
                 POST   /:slug/bays(.:format)              bays#create
         new_bay GET    /:slug/bays/new(.:format)          bays#new
        edit_bay GET    /:slug/bays/:id/edit(.:format)     bays#edit
             bay GET    /:slug/bays/:id(.:format)          bays#show
                 PATCH  /:slug/bays/:id(.:format)          bays#update
                 PUT    /:slug/bays/:id(.:format)          bays#update
                 DELETE /:slug/bays/:id(.:format)          bays#destroy
```

Now when i run rpec for bays controller, i caught with following error.

```
 Failure/Error: get :index, {}, valid_session
 ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
   No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"bays"}
```

Using

```
rspec-rails (3.0.1)
rails (4.0.0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have defined it... bays index requires a `:slug` parameter. According to the error message, you have passed no slug to this route. You must either pass `:slug` (eg `get :index, :slug => "1234", valid_session`) or redefine the route to not need it.

for testing routes in rspec... That's a basic part of rspec: [rspec routing specs](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-4/docs/routing-specs)

in your case it'd be something like:

```
{ :get => "/1234/bays" }.
  should route_to(
    :controller => "bays",
    :slug => "1234"
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

For rspec 3.x you can go with:

```
  scenario 'get correct slug', :type => :routing do
    expect(get("/models/slug")).to route_to(:controller => "controller_name", :action => 'action_name', :id => "your_slug_name")
  end
```

Note the `type: :routing` definition before the block.

More info [here](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-5/docs/routing-specs/route-to-matcher).